# If $(m-n)^2 = 48$, $m^2 + n = 30$, then what is the value of $mn/3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $(m-n)^2 = 48$, $m^2 + n = 30$, then what is the value of $mn/3$?

Comment: Do you really mean $m^2+n=30$, or is it supposed to be $m^2+n^2=30$? Also, what have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, you should show your workings please.

Comment: I *really* doubt your gave the problem correctly.

Answer (score 2):

$n= 30 - m^2$

So $(m-n)^2 = (m^2 +m -30)^2 = 48$

So $m^2 + m - 30 =\pm 4\sqrt 3$.

So $m^2 + 2\frac 12m + \frac 14 = 30 + \frac 14 \pm 4\sqrt 3$

$(m+\frac 12)^2= 30\frac 14 \pm 4\sqrt 3$

$m + \frac 12 = \pm \sqrt{30\frac 14 \pm 4\sqrt 3}$

$m =-\frac 12\pm \sqrt{30\frac 14 \pm 4\sqrt 3}$

So $\frac {mn}3 = \frac {m(30-m^2)}3 = \frac {(\pm \sqrt{30\frac 14 \pm 4\sqrt 3})(30 -(-\frac 12\mp \sqrt{30\frac 14 \pm 4\sqrt 3})^2)}3$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant $(m-n)^{2} = 48$ and $m^{2} + n^{2} = 30$. If this is the case, one may solve it as it follows
\begin{align*}
m^{2} - 2mn + n^{2} = 48 \Longleftrightarrow 30 - 2mn = 48 \Longleftrightarrow mn = -9 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{mn}{3} = -3
\end{align*}